# Parse Right Aligned Multi-Line Text File Report

Tags: python, pandas, report, multiline

I have a text file I am reading in that is not delimited in any way. The only consistency it has is being right aligned and based on position. Though, the first and last field on each line is not right aligned. I'd love to get this into a `pandas` dataframe. The body of the report looks like these two records below:

```
CK        1234567891   CNS       2345678912  SCHD               0.00           75.00  Doe, John
CAC2       55,147.07   CPLO            0.00  EL                 0.00              N   Insufficient funds to process allotment.
ACT                    ACT             BILL                        0
                                                                     01-15-2022 MNTH

CK        3456789123   LEAS      4567891234  BOXP              35.00            0.00  Doe, Jane
CACK            0.00   SDB             0.00  EL                 0.00              N   Insufficient funds to process allotment.
ACT                    ACT                          02-05-2022     0      02-05-2022  Safe Deposit Box Rent
```

I'm having trouble parsing this and could use some help. A major issue is that There are `null` values (whitespace in this case) that splitting and stripping are not accounting for. Thus, I am ending up with different lengths of lists when apppending. Examples of this are 'BILL' in the first data grouping as well as '02-05-2022' and 'Safe Deposit Box Rent' in the second data grouping.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your file is delimited by arbitraries fields sizes.

If all the file have same structure, the code below create a list of key/value from most of fields:

```
import re

textFile = [str,str2,str3,str4,str5,str6,str7]
#Field sizes (initial and final char position)
fieldSizes = ((0,20),(23,43),(45,68),(69,84),(86,200))
fields = []

with open("yourfile.txt", "r") as f:
  textFile = f.readlines()

for line in textFile: 
  for i in range (len(fieldSizes)):
    #Split substring based on fieldSizes
    field = line[fieldSizes[i][0]:fieldSizes[i][1]]
    #Replace 2 or more spaces for ! (random separator)
    field = re.sub(r' {2,30}',"!", field)
    #Split based on separator
    field = field.split("!")
    fields.append(field)
print(fields)
```

**Output** (based on your example):

```
[['CK', '1234567891'],
 ['CNS', '2345678912'],
 ['SCHD', '0.00'],
 ['', '75.00'],
 ['Doe, John\n'],
 ['CAC2', '55,147.07'],
 ['CPLO', '0.00'],
 ['EL', '0.00'],
 ['', 'N '],
 ['Insufficient funds to process allotment.\n'],
 ['ACT', ''],
 ['ACT', 'BILL'],
 ['', '0'],
 [''],
 [''],
 ['', ''],
 ['', ''],
 ['', ''],
 ['01-15-2022 MNTH'],
 [''],
 ['\n'],
 [''],
 [''],
 [''],
 [''],
 ['CK', '3456789123'],
 ['LEAS', '4567891234'],
 ['BOXP', '35.00'],
 ['', '0.00'],
 ['Doe, Jane\n'],
 ['CACK', '0.00'],
 ['SDB', '0.00'],
 ['EL', '0.00'],
 ['', 'N '],
 ['Insufficient funds to process allotment.\n'],
 ['ACT', ''],
 ['ACT', ''],
 ['', '02-05-2022', '0'],
 ['', '02-05-2022'],
 ['Safe Deposit Box Rent']]
```